# Github pages rendering user Pages instead of project pages (using reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, create-react-app, github-pages

I have a user page deployed at [deekshithanand.github.io](https://deekshithanand.github.io). The page is written using `create-react-app`. Now I have another project repo [React-Mission-List](https://github.com/deekshithanand/React-Mission-List), which is a simple todo created using create-react-app. I have deployed this [here](https://deekshithanand.github.io/React-Mission-List/). I have deployed all the apps using gh-pages and I have included the homepage attribute to their respective URLs in package.json file of the respective projects.

The problem is whenever I visit any project page, it shows the user page only. How can the project page be displayed? One more thing I noticed is whatever I put after the URL
`deekshithanand.github.io/` it simply shows the user page.

If anyone has any hint or solution, Please help!

Comment: I see the to do list on `/React-Mission-List`

Comment: @sudobangbang here is what I did after posting the question. I removed the service worker call for both the user page and the todo app and deployed. And after your comment, I opened in  incognito and it works. But in normal chrome window it shows the same old user page even for todo page. Is the issue related to some caching error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to caching! I had registered the service worker. 
I changed the code from `serviceWorker.register();`  to `serviceWorker.unregister();` and redeployed using gh-pages.

And upon hard-refreshing the page (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), the other project pages started to show whenever I used that URL instead of user pages.

Hope that helps someone! Happy coding!